# How to base64 encode Object of type ZipFile

Tags: python, base64, zip

I have a zip file that is in memory and I would like to convert it into a base64 encoded utf-8 string for another function to parse downstream.

The file is created as follows

```
data = BytesIO()
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(data, 'w')
zip.writestr(test.csv, 'Hello world')
zip.close()
data.close()

b64zip = base64.b64encode(zip)
```

However, when trying to base64 encode the zip file I get the following error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'ZipFile'
```

How can I convert this ZipFile object into a base64 encoded string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip files are byte encoded so use:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(data, 'rb')
```